# Apply same operations to different data frames in R

Tags: r

I am trying to apply same functions to several data frames. My data looks like this. I have several data frames for different years. I want to get rid of year specific names in order to merge data frames into one.

| ID | educ_1995 | year_1995 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| k1 | 0 | 1995 |
| k2 | 1 | 1995 |
| k3 | 0 | 1995 |

I have tried following:

```
files <- list(workers_1995, workers_1996)
files <- lapply(files, function)
# I tried to make a list of my data frames and then write a function for them. 


myfunc <- function(files){
  files %>% 
    rename(igang=starts_with("igang")) %>% 
    rename(year=starts_with("year")) 
}
```

I would like to get the results in form of same tibbles, but with changed names.

Comment: The function that is lapply'd should be the function you've defined, i.e. `myfunc`. Try replacing `function` in the apply with `myfunc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the order and place `myfunc` inside the parentheses:

```r
files <- list(workers_1995, workers_1996)

myfunc <- function(onefile){
  onefile %>% 
    rename(igang=starts_with("igang")) %>% 
    rename(year=starts_with("year")) 
}

lapply(files, myfunc)
```

Comment: Not a big thing, but this can be done in one `rename` call: `purrr::map(files, ~ rename(.x, igang = starts_with("igang"), year = starts_with("year")))`